# How to force NTPD to update date/time after boot?

Tags: raspbian, ntp

The Raspberry Pi lacks a hardware clock. How do I force NTPD to update date/time immediately after every boot?

I'm running [Raspbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspbian#Software) and the Raspberry Pi is connected using an [Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet) cable.

Comment: Mine already does that out of the box. What disto are you using?

Comment: Raspbian Wheezy

Comment: works as it is, somehow

Comment: You need Internet connectivity for ntpd to have servers to ask.

Comment: @Thorb Pi is connected with ethernet cable / dhcp. It simply does not get a valid date after booting, it takes a while (10 to 45 minutes)

Comment: It will do it on its own, when set up properly, within a few minutes.  You might also want to be sure you are set to the correct master clock time source:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68811/how-do-i-set-raspbian-to-use-the-primary-time-server-time-nist-gov

Comment: It will do it automatically, after a couple of minutes.  Be sure you have set it to use the Master Clock at the National Bureau of Standards, time.nist.gov  as described here: 
 https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68811/how-do-i-set-raspbian-to-use-the-primary-time-server-time-nist-gov/68812#68812

Comment: The simplest and quickest is still (15 march 13h 01) being root or sudo-ed :

"date -s 03151301"
This is of course not an answer.

Comment: Seems that no one has yet answered this question satisfactorily - i.e. how to sync time via NTP after a boot (i.e. without rebooting).

Answer (score 54):

After searching around, this method worked for me.
As you know, the Raspberry Pi 3 has NTP disabled by default.
So by just typing this, the NTP support will be enabled:

```
sudo timedatectl set-ntp True
```

Check result with `timedatectl status`

In case of warning, you may have to run `sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc true` too.

Comment: Thanks, this finally helped me out, and seems to be the proper way, despite previous answers.

Comment: That is the best answer, helped me a lot. You can use 'sudo' to avoid typing your password (useful for scripts that run it). What is the purpose of the seconds command? set-local-rtc

Answer (score 45):

Do an `apt-get install ntpdate` .

`ntpdate` will run when an Ethernet interface is brought up, and set the time from an ntp server (see `/etc/default/ntpdate`).

If `ntpd` is running, ntpdate will do nothing, however `ntpdate` will run prior to `ntpd` at bootup - so this should work out to set the time at bootup as long as there's an Ethernet connection.

Comment: stock Raspbian will have all this already.

Comment: @scruss mine didn't. (2013-02-09 wheezy rasbian)

Comment: Mine also did not, had to do it manually.

Comment: If it is set up correctly it will do it automatically - although it may take a few minutes.

Comment: `Linux raspberrypi 4.14.30-v7+ #1102 SMP Mon Mar 26 16:45:49 BST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux` didn't have it too.

Comment: "Ethernet" is a misnomer here. A valid connection to a specified server is required (not necessarily Ethernet).

Answer (score 44):

If your clock is way off, you may need to force ntp to sync by doing:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ntp stop
sudo ntpd -q -g
sudo /etc/init.d/ntp start
```

Comment: It returns error "sudo: ntpd: command not found"

Comment: ntpd must be installed to use the command

Comment: It **is** installed, I am not that ignorant :)

Comment: Could you please visit http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47542/raspberry-pi-wont-update-time ? I have posted details there.

Comment: This was absolutely the solution to my problem, but I found it to be temporary until I rebooted.  Eventually I caught an error in the shutdown that it couldn't update the hwclock because the hw clock had a future date (no idea how that happened).  But the solution was a hwclock update force.  That forced the update to the fake hardware clock and then on boot the time was at least close to the current so ntp could do it's job normally.

Comment: It is possible to pass those arguments to the `ntpd` daemon along with its configuration file. Don't use `/etc/ntp.conf` as it is the wrong configuration file and is likely to be overwritten at boot. IIRC you should be able to put these startup parameters in `/etc/default/ntpd`.

Comment: /etc/init.d/ntp does not exist

Comment: Indeed - `ntp` is no longer installed by default (since `stretch` in 2017). Here's [some background on that change](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/87921/83790) if you're interested.

Answer (score 27):

This question is apparently being "recycled" for some reason, and so it seems appropriate to recycle some old answers also :)

#### The year is now 2023...

This question was asked in 2013. `ntpd` was the timekeeping software included in the [Raspbian distribution at that time (`wheezy`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspbian). However, that changed with the `stretch` distribution in 2017 when `systemd-timesyncd` replaced `ntpd`. The reasons for this change, and some of the technical tradeoffs were discussed in [this old answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/87921/83790) for those who are interested in such things.

With respect to the question here, perhaps the most salient point in the ***current environment*** (*bullseye* & onward, post-`systemd`) is this: If you decide to install `ntpd` (now `ntpsec`) under your current Raspbian distribution, you will be required to REMOVE `systemd-timesyncd`. IOW, Debian has declared other timekeeping services in *conflict* at the **`apt` package level**. This method of *conflict resolution* required Debian to break `systemd-timesyncd` out as a separate package (apart from `systemd`), and declare a [*virtual package*](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#virtual-packages) called [`time-daemon`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/time-daemon). (See [REFERENCE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/758100/in-debian-bullseye-does-systemd-timesyncd-check-for-other-ntp-daemons))

Note that this method of conflict resolution is (may be) unique to Debian-based distros such as **raspbian**, and has been fairly recently developed. During an earlier time (e.g. Aug 2018), `systemd-timesyncd` would "excuse itself" by checking for the presence of other NTP daemons. Earlier versions of the config file for `systemd-timesyncd` (listed via `systemctl cat systemd-timesyncd`) included the following `ConditionFileIsExecutable` statements:

```
# Under earlier (e.g. Aug 2018) releases of raspbian:
$ systemctl cat systemd-timesyncd
```

Note the last few lines of the ouput listing:

> # don't run timesyncd if we have another NTP daemon installed
> ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/ntpd
> ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/openntpd
> ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/chronyd
> ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/VBoxService

In other words: `systemd-timesyncd` checks to see if any of these alternative time services are running on your system, and if so, politely defers to them for providing your timekeeping services. It is left to the reader to decide whether the *Debian method of conflict resolution* is superior or inferior to using the `ConditionFileIsExecutable` statements.

#### "force" `ntpd` to update after boot?!

This was the OP's question. The answer (in 2023) hasn't changed: **It shouldn't be necessary to do this on any RPi system - *unless someone has changed the default configuration*!** You can verify this as follows:

```bash
$ timedatectl
               Local time: Wed 2021-01-13 00:25:33 GMT
           Universal time: Wed 2021-01-13 00:25:33 UTC
                 RTC time: n/a
                Time zone: Europe/London (GMT, +0000)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

Note two items:

1. `System clock synchronized: yes`
2. `NTP service: active`

Item 1. tells you your system clock is synchronized with whatever the default time source is, and Item 2. is **nearly** true in that RPi uses the `SNTP` protocol by default instead of `NTP` ([REF](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/87921/83790)); i.e. this means RPi has a time source, and it is using it.

I think that's all that's needed for an **up-to-date answer for 2023**, except this: read `man timedatectl` to learn more about its capabilities.

Comment: System clock synchronized: no

Comment: @Arrow_Raider: Yer' point being???

Comment: Actually, the statement that Raspian(Debian) will "do the right thing" and "it just works" are at odds with one another; if the NTP daemon is installed in the '/usr/local/sbin' directory---which it is and should be if you build it yourself---then "it DOES NOT work". You must find the file that controls that list and add the correct entry.

Comment: @StevenHigh: It does work if `ntp` is installed using `apt`. I've not tried building NTP myself, so I'll take your word for it. As a suggestion, perhaps it would be more useful if you added your own answer to address this situation? In particular, how is it that `systemd-timesyncd` "loses" `ntp` just because it's installed in a different directory. And more importantly, how could this be corrected?

Comment: @Seamus, When I attempted to add my own explanation, I had my comment excised and got yelled a for going "off-topic". The Best Practices way of installing local system binaries---an NTP built from sources, say---is to install the binaries in '/usr/local/sbin' and '/usr/local/bin'; the timesyncd does NOT search '/usr/local' for installed binaries. So the fix involves adding the '/usr/local/sbin/ntpd' and so on, to the config files, which I can't place in a comment. I would LOVE to post an answer here on how to do that.

Comment: @StevenHigh: Good for you! And yeah - answers are usually better than comments; it's all part of the [rules](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) here, so you shouldn't take it personally. We can't have a *free-for-all*, now can we?  :)

Comment: "do the right thing". "it just works". The year is 2021 and it is still not working. I had my pi connected to the guest wlan of the router and it didn't work ("System clock synchronized: no"). Switching to the the private wlan resolved it.

Comment: @Markus: What have you tried to find the cause - other than sarcasm?

Comment: @Seamus it might be worth mentioning that the pi has to be connected to the internet (obviously) and that the router may not block UDP port 123, which is used for ntp. This port will most likely not be blocked in a default configured router. In my case (using default configured guest wifi) this port was blocked. Maybe add a short command to the post on how to check whether UDP port 123 is reachable. Unluckily I couldn't find a method to test this yet. I tried `nc -z -v -u google.com 123` which always succeeds.

Comment: @Markus: "It might be worth mentioning..."  Except that it has nothing to do with the original question. If you feel differently, perhaps you should put all of that in your own answer?

Comment: My Pi was VLANed off on boot which means - no NTP sync.
Had to allow public net and reboot Pi.

Some have an internal NTP off switches/routers/DHCP so it's not obvious to have internet access there!

Answer (score 20):

If you set the Time Zone in `raspi-config` the Raspberry Pi will automatically update the time on boot, if connected to the internet.

1. `sudo raspi-config`
2. Select `Internationalisation Options`
3. Select `I2 Change Timezone`
4. Select your Geographical Area
5. Select your nearest City
6. Select `Finish`
7. Select `Yes` to reboot now

Comment: this worked well for me

Comment: `I2 Change Timezone` option doesn't exist any more

Comment: It does exist, at least in Raspbian Buster.

Comment: "Internationalisation Options" is now called "Localisation Options"

Comment: "nearest city" is not the proper way. you need to select the city where your time zone belongs, which may be the nearest, or not...

Answer (score 13):

See forum post *[Time does not sync on Pi 3 and with official dongle](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=141454)*.

[ntpd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntpd) emits IP/UDP packets with the ToS field set to 0xc0. So that is quite similar to the other issue I (and many others) have with Raspberry Pi3 when operated over a Wi-Fi internal interface.

As a workaround, add the command

```
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -I POSTROUTING 1 -o wlan0 -p udp --dport 123 -j TOS --set-tos 0x00
```

to the file

```
/etc/rc.local
```

before the exit 0 line. Next, reboot and check.

Comment: I had the same issue as Iinstalled the RPi3 I got for XMas,and you solved my problem. Great !!!

Answer (score 8):

It should already be updating the time. The NTPD server should start just after the swap file and before SSHD.

Check your /etc/ntp.conf file to make sure it is configured.

It should list at least one server. I use time.nrc.ca for my server.

Manual page for ntp.conf is here:
http://linux.die.net/man/5/ntp.conf

Answer (score 3):

My son's Rasberry Pi would not update the time out of the box and after trying all the suggestions above I could get it to update manually but not automatically. Finally after looking elsewhere as well without success, I found that the ntp.conf file that came with the Rasberry Pi had the following lines commented out:

```
#restrict 127.0.0.1
#restrict ::1
```

I used

```
sudo nano /etc/ntp.conf
```

in the terminal to edit the ntp conf file to now be:

```
# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely. 
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
```

That solved the problem for us. It updates with both the WiFi and the ethernet cable. I don't know if it would update with WiFi without the change to rc.local suggested above, as by the time I found the solution above I had already made that change and I have not undone it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use ntp to solve the issue. There is a script that reads the date from a server and you only need set the date to be the result of that script (your Raspberry Pi needs to be connected to the internet). Then, you need to run that command at startup.

**Step1:** Retrieve the date from a server.

```
sudo date -s "$(wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | grep Date: | cut -d' ' -f5-8)Z"
```

**Step2:** Run the command at startup by adding it to the file `/etc/rc.local` (Worked on Ubuntu 16.04).

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

**CREDITS:**

1- https://askubuntu.com/a/655528/572294

2- https://askubuntu.com/a/1199/572294

Comment: You may not need to use `ntp` but you should. It's better, faster, more accurate, and the industry standard. Don't make up your own weird things when good standards exist please.

Comment: It doesn't help much if your RasPi is running 24/7.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with a Pi not syncing. None of these solutions worked. Turns out my network environment was blocking the NTP port (123).
The solution for me was

```
sudo apt install htpdate
```

taken from:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=222236

Which updates the system clock through HTTP calls instead.

Comment: Yes, this works nice in my work environment, where most ports (other then 80) are blocked.

Answer (score 2):

I found the `timedatectl` application to help me when I was having a similar issue.  It's installed by default and '--help' gives a pretty good and simple overview of how to use the tool.

Note: make sure  your timezone is set properly, which this tool can do as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is the approach I ended up taking. Many of these answers seemed to indicate things that just didn't check out when I looked at my Raspian system:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

I had nothing that appeared in logs indicating that `timedatectl` was doing anything, or that `ntp` was syncing on the NIC's up state, or that NTPD was even installed/configured.

In the end I merely added this to my `/etc/rc.local`:

```
$ cat /etc/rc.local
logger "Beginning force syncing NTP..."
service ntp stop
ntpd -gq
service ntp start
logger "Finished force syncing NTP..."
```

And installed `ntp`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ntp
```

Which results in this in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Aug  5 09:10:20 pi-hole ntp[526]: Starting NTP server: ntpd.
Aug  5 09:10:20 pi-hole ntpd[555]: proto: precision = 1.458 usec (-19)
Aug  5 09:10:20 pi-hole ntpd[555]: Listen and drop on 0 v6wildcard [::]:123
Aug  5 09:10:20 pi-hole ntpd[555]: Listen and drop on 1 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123
Aug  5 09:10:20 pi-hole ntpd[555]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1:123
Aug  5 09:10:20 pi-hole ntpd[555]: Listen normally on 3 eth0 192.168.1.85:123
Aug  5 09:10:20 pi-hole ntpd[555]: Listen normally on 4 lo [::1]:123
Aug  5 09:10:20 pi-hole ntpd[555]: Listen normally on 5 eth0 [fe80::f5ea:7663:4ec:784d%2]:123
Aug  5 09:10:20 pi-hole ntpd[555]: Listening on routing socket on fd #22 for interface updates
Aug  5 09:10:21 pi-hole ntpd[555]: ntpd exiting on signal 15 (Terminated)
Aug  5 09:10:21 pi-hole ntp[661]: Stopping NTP server: ntpd.
Aug  5 09:10:21 pi-hole ntpd[674]: ntpd 4.2.8p10@1.3728-o Sat Mar 10 18:03:33 UTC 2018 (1): Starting
Aug  5 09:10:21 pi-hole ntpd[674]: Command line: ntpd -gq
Aug  5 09:10:21 pi-hole ntpd[674]: proto: precision = 0.625 usec (-21)
Aug  5 09:10:21 pi-hole ntpd[674]: Listen and drop on 0 v6wildcard [::]:123
Aug  5 09:10:21 pi-hole ntpd[674]: Listen and drop on 1 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123
Aug  5 09:10:21 pi-hole ntpd[674]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1:123
Aug  5 09:10:21 pi-hole ntpd[674]: Listen normally on 3 eth0 192.168.1.85:123
Aug  5 09:10:21 pi-hole ntpd[674]: Listen normally on 4 lo [::1]:123
Aug  5 09:10:21 pi-hole ntpd[674]: Listen normally on 5 eth0 [fe80::f5ea:7663:4ec:784d%2]:123
Aug  5 09:10:21 pi-hole ntpd[674]: Listening on routing socket on fd #22 for interface updates
Aug  5 09:10:34 pi-hole ntpd[674]: Soliciting pool server 198.98.57.16
Aug  5 09:10:35 pi-hole ntpd[674]: Soliciting pool server 74.82.59.149
Aug  5 09:10:36 pi-hole ntpd[674]: Soliciting pool server 23.131.160.7
Aug  5 09:10:36 pi-hole ntpd[674]: Soliciting pool server 52.37.26.163
Aug  5 09:10:36 pi-hole ntpd[674]: Soliciting pool server 204.2.134.163
Aug  5 09:10:36 pi-hole ntpd[674]: Soliciting pool server 96.126.100.203
Aug  5 09:10:36 pi-hole ntpd[674]: Soliciting pool server 199.223.248.101
Aug  5 09:10:36 pi-hole ntpd[674]: Soliciting pool server 66.228.42.59
Aug  5 09:10:36 pi-hole ntpd[674]: Soliciting pool server 208.75.89.4
Aug  5 09:10:37 pi-hole ntpd[674]: Soliciting pool server 204.2.134.164
Aug  5 09:10:37 pi-hole ntpd[674]: Soliciting pool server 104.236.116.147
Aug  5 09:10:38 pi-hole ntpd[674]: Soliciting pool server 204.9.54.119
Aug  5 09:10:48 pi-hole ntpd[674]: ntpd: time set +6.769186 s
Aug  5 09:10:49 pi-hole ntpd[853]: ntpd 4.2.8p10@1.3728-o Sat Mar 10 18:03:33 UTC 2018 (1): Starting
Aug  5 09:10:49 pi-hole ntpd[853]: Command line: /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 111:114
Aug  5 09:10:49 pi-hole ntp[844]: Starting NTP server: ntpd.
Aug  5 09:10:49 pi-hole ntpd[856]: proto: precision = 0.625 usec (-21)
Aug  5 09:10:49 pi-hole ntpd[856]: Listen and drop on 0 v6wildcard [::]:123
Aug  5 09:10:49 pi-hole ntpd[856]: Listen and drop on 1 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123
Aug  5 09:10:49 pi-hole ntpd[856]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1:123
Aug  5 09:10:49 pi-hole ntpd[856]: Listen normally on 3 eth0 192.168.1.85:123
Aug  5 09:10:49 pi-hole ntpd[856]: Listen normally on 4 lo [::1]:123
Aug  5 09:10:49 pi-hole ntpd[856]: Listen normally on 5 eth0 [fe80::f5ea:7663:4ec:784d%2]:123
Aug  5 09:10:49 pi-hole ntpd[856]: Listening on routing socket on fd #22 for interface updates
Aug  5 09:10:49 pi-hole root: Finished force syncing NTP...
```

Comment: Doesn't work on minimal raspbian: `Failed to start ntp.service: Unit ntp.service not found.` And ntpd doesn't exist either. The Pi definitely eventually gains time. (I'm looking into this because my HTTPS curls fail without -k when run prior to that)

Comment: @StevenLu - I'll update the A'er to include the install of ntp as well.

Comment: @StevenLu - `apt-get install ntp`

Comment: Or download the latest version from: [link](https://www.ntp.org/downloads.html). This ensures your build is at the latest revision. You will want to use the hold argument for apt to keep Raspian from regressing to the build on the site.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following on the default image to sync time without installing additional packages:

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 0
timedatectl set-ntp 1
timedatectl status
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this somewhere on the interwebs. Seems to work on Buster:

```
sudo timedatectl set-ntp false && sudo timedatectl set-time "$(date --iso-8601=seconds | cut -d "+" -f1 | tr T ' ')" && sudo timedatectl set-ntp true
```

I'm not sure if the intermediate command (`set-time`) is really needed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I did timedatectl and got everything looking fine.

But my raspberry pi never syncs clock when it is wrong.  Typical problem scenario for me:

- restore SD card from backup
- boot is very slow
- problems with ssh, ssl certificates
- eventually realise the clock is wrong (showing the time approx when the backup was created).
- try running various ntpd commands
- eventually give up and set clock manually.

When I looked at it before, it seemed that some of the network startup was failing or not working properly because of the wrong clock, and this was interfering with clock sync.

What I would like is a way to force nptd to ignore all certificate expiry etc and just force an update of the clock, and for this to be something that reliably happens during boot, however far out the clock is.

I don't think this question is answered.

Comment: Have you disabled all of the systemd-timesyncd pieces? Once you've done that running `sudo ntpd -g -q` forces an update of the clock.

Comment: The problem is on startup. It doesn't start up properly if the clock is wrong.  Lots of things don't work very well with a wrong clock, including remote login.  So I still don't think the question is answered.

I want a way that I can configure my RPi, so that *on startup*, however far wrong the clock is, it corrects it and performs a normal startup without interaction.  

It feels like a catch 22:
- accurate-ish clock setting is needed for network startup. 
- Network startup is needed for accurate clock setting.

Comment: That's the purpose of fake-hwclock to give you an approximate time of day until the RPi gets online and can sync to an NTP server. `sudo ntpd -g -q` is guaranteed to set the clock (if online) as it overrides the 1000s limit on clock drift.  This stuff all works on my RPis and within a minute of booting the clocks are all correctly sync'd.

Comment: No it still doesn't work.  I had to replace my SD card a few days ago. Clock was totally wrong and all ntp commands would not work until I set the clock manually.

Comment: Important to clarify that the problem for me is on startup.  I have various other devices including dhcp and bind running.  It could be that these refuse to start up without approximately correct clocks, and that might be why I don't get a working network in order to set clocks.

Perhaps the question in my case could be clarified as 'how do I automatically set the clock on startup when the device itself is the local dns server?

Answer (score 0):

I solved that in `/etc/rc.local` by adding at the end (before any `exit 0`):

```
sleep 10
ntpdate -u tempus1.gum.gov.pl > /dev/null
```

Sleep is needed because of starting Ethernet connection. Then immediately Pi synces date and time on each boot.

Check if you have rc.local service first (run at boot) as some of the recent systems lack it. If it does not exist - add it.

Also you can put the below in `/etc/crontab`:

```
59 */3  * * *   root    ntpdate -u tempus1.gum.gov.pl > /dev/null
```