# Time is most important thing in my project

Tags: raspbian

I work on a project that date and time is very important. 
I want force raspberry to sync time with a ntp server and if time not sync raspberry won't boot or wait for time sync and after succeed resume boot. 
How can I do it?

Comment: Please check http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/how-to-force-ntpd-to-update-date-time-after-boot if it answers your question.

Comment: Without knowing what the project is - wouldn't it be easier to just wait until the time syncs as determined from your program rather than interrupt the boot process? The Pi syncs via NTP by default. If time is that critical you may want to add a RTC as well.

Comment: For the best time accuracy be sure to set it to the master clock:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68811/how-do-i-set-raspbian-to-use-the-primary-time-server-time-nist-gov