# Error while trying to install pubnub using pip

Tags: pip

I tried installing pubnub. I went through the website of pubnub and did as it was told on the website.
https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-07-22-getting-started-with-raspberry-pi-2-and-pubnub-in-python-programming-language/

While I tried to do pip install pubnub (sudo pip install pubnub), the following error occured. I can't install it no matter how much I try.

Here is the error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1178, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 196, in find_requirement
    url_name = self._find_url_name(Link(self.index_urls[0], trusted=True), url_name, req) or req.url_name
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 361, in _find_url_name
    page = self._get_page(index_url, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_page
    session=self.session,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 694, in get_page
    req, link, "connection error: %s" % exc, url,
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type Error)

Storing debug log for failure in /home/pi/.pip/pip.log
```

Does anybody have any solution so that I can install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check your Raspberry pi time. Sometimes it so happens when your system time is inaccurate the pip installation fails. I have faced this issue once.

You may check the articles below on how to set the time.
[How to force NTPD to update date/time after boot?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/how-to-force-ntpd-to-update-date-time-after-boot)

Hope this helps.