# How to sync system clock?

Tags: system-clock, buildroot, systemd-timesyncd

I have built a custom Linux OS for Raspberry Pi CM4 using Buildroot. I am able to boot it but my system clock is not synchronized. Its set to some static time and I want to show real time instead. I have selected `BR2_PACKAGE_RTC_TOOLS=y`, `BR2_PACKAGE_UTIL_LINUX_HWCLOCK=y` and `BR2_PACKAGE_NTP=y`, `BR2_PACKAGE_NTP_NTPDATE=y`, `BR2_PACKAGE_NTP_NTPTIME=y` in `menuconfig`. But still it's same result.

The `timedatectl` shows:

```
Local time: Tue 2022-01-18 11:52:05 UTC
           Universal time: Tue 2022-01-18 11:52:05 UTC
                 RTC time: n/a
                Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

The `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd` shows:

```
systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled;
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-01-18 11:35:47 UTC; 17min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
   Main PID: 194 (systemd-timesyn)
     Status: "Daemon is running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 1009)
        CPU: 396ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-timesyncd.service
             └─194 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd

Jan 18 11:35:46 br2rauc systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
Jan 18 11:35:47 br2rauc systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
```

And `timedatectl show-timesync` results in:

```
FallbackNTPServers=time1.google.com time2.google.com time3.google.com time4.google.com
RootDistanceMaxUSec=5s
PollIntervalMinUSec=32s
PollIntervalMaxUSec=34min 8s
PollIntervalUSec=0
Frequency=0
```

I don't know why but `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` looks like not set

```
[Time]
#NTP=
#FallbackNTP=time1.google.com time2.google.com time3.google.com time4.google.com
#RootDistanceMaxSec=5
#PollIntervalMinSec=32
#PollIntervalMaxSec=2048
#SaveIntervalSec=60
```

Do I need to set any value for `NTP`?

I also tried by enabling `BR2_PACKAGE_HTPDATE=y` and `systemctl status htpdate.status` shows:

```
htpdate.service - htpdate daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/htpdate.service; enabled; vendor pr
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-01-18 11:35:48 UTC; 22min ago
    Process: 221 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/htpdate -D -i /run/htpdate.pid $HTPDATE_ARG
   Main PID: 228 (htpdate)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 1009)
        CPU: 26ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/htpdate.service
             └─228 /usr/sbin/htpdate -D -i /run/htpdate.pid -a -s -t https:/

Jan 18 11:35:48 br2rauc systemd[1]: Starting htpdate daemon...
Jan 18 11:35:48 br2rauc htpdate[228]: htpdate version 1.3.3 started
Jan 18 11:35:48 br2rauc htpdate[228]: www.google.com host or service unavailable
Jan 18 11:35:48 br2rauc systemd[1]: Started htpdate daemon.
```

As you can see above date and time is set to Jan 18. While booting Pi is not connected to internet. And I connect to internet using `connman` after system boot. But again after restarting `systemd-timesyncd` it's same result.

Can anyone please let me know how to properly synchronize the system clock?

Your help will be much appreciated.

thanks in advance

P.S: Please let me know if any info is missing here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force NTPD to update date/time after boot?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/how-to-force-ntpd-to-update-date-time-after-boot)

Comment: `sudo timedatectl` shows that something has set your clock to the correct time. So what's your question?

Comment: Hello @Dougie, as you can see above, both local time and Universal time is set to 2022-01-18 but I have posted this yesterday so I expect it to be 2022-04-14. But I could change the time zone to CET from UTC in Buildroot. But after boot date is still the same.

Comment: If your RPi (any version) is running RaspiOS and is connected to the public internet then there's a process built-in to periodically sync the clock to an internet time server. There's also fake-hwclock which records the time at 17 minutes past every hour and automatically resets the clock to that when it boots. If you don't have an internet connection you will need extra RTC hardware.

Comment: The main thing to note is that Raspberry Pis don't have a built-in hardware clock like regular computers (PCs).