# Cant get NTP service working on PI

Tags: ntp

I've read a few posts on here about this and I can't seem to solve it. The NTP service will not start with my pi.

Model 4B Revision 1.2 (4 GB)

I'm in a situation where the pi is blocked from internet but we have some local time servers setup. When I manually run:

```
   sudo ntpdate -s 192.168.2.247
```

This works fine and updates to the correct time from our local server, but the service will not start with the pi booting and I cant figure out why.

I have disabled systemd-timesyncd

Output of status on ntp:
sudo service ntp status

```
● ntp.service - Network Time Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ntp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-09-23 17:16:34 MST; 1min 32s ago
     Docs: man:ntpd(8)
  Process: 468 ExecStart=/usr/lib/ntp/ntp-systemd-wrapper (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 499 (ntpd)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ntp.service
           └─499 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 111:116

Sep 23 17:16:34 allsky ntpd[499]: Listening on routing socket on fd #20 for interface updates
Sep 23 17:16:34 allsky ntpd[499]: kernel reports TIME_ERROR: 0x41: Clock Unsynchronized
Sep 23 17:16:34 allsky ntpd[499]: kernel reports TIME_ERROR: 0x41: Clock Unsynchronized
Sep 23 17:16:44 allsky ntpd[499]: bind(23) AF_INET6 fe80::af86:b202:dbb6:9953%2#123 flags 0x11 failed: Cannot assi
Sep 23 17:16:44 allsky ntpd[499]: unable to create socket on eth0 (4) for fe80::af86:b202:dbb6:9953%2#123
Sep 23 17:16:44 allsky ntpd[499]: failed to init interface for address fe80::af86:b202:dbb6:9953%2
Sep 23 17:16:46 allsky ntpd[499]: Listen normally on 5 eth0 [fe80::af86:b202:dbb6:9953%2]:123
Sep 23 17:16:46 allsky ntpd[499]: new interface(s) found: waking up resolver
Sep 23 17:16:49 allsky ntpd[499]: Listen normally on 6 eth0 192.167.1.52:123
Sep 23 17:16:49 allsky ntpd[499]: new interface(s) found: waking up resolver
```

Config file:

```
cat /etc/ntp.conf
# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

# Leap seconds definition provided by tzdata
leapfile /usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list

# Enable this if you want statistics to be logged.
#statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable


# You do need to talk to an NTP server or two (or three).
#server ntp.your-provider.example
server  192.168.2.248
server  192.168.2.52
server  192.168.2.55
server  192.168.2.17
#server 192.168.2.16
#server 192.168.2.247

# pool.ntp.org maps to about 1000 low-stratum NTP servers.  Your server will
# pick a different set every time it starts up.  Please consider joining the
# pool: <http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html>
pool 0.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
#pool 1.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
#pool 2.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst
#pool 3.debian.pool.ntp.org iburst


# Access control configuration; see /usr/share/doc/ntp-doc/html/accopt.html for
# details.  The web page <http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/AccessRestrictions>
# might also be helpful.
#
# Note that "restrict" applies to both servers and clients, so a configuration
# that might be intended to block requests from certain clients could also end
# up blocking replies from your own upstream servers.

# By default, exchange time with everybody, but don't allow configuration.
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited

# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

# Needed for adding pool entries
restrict source notrap nomodify noquery

# Clients from this (example!) subnet have unlimited access, but only if
# cryptographically authenticated.
#restrict 192.168.123.0 mask 255.255.255.0 notrust


# If you want to provide time to your local subnet, change the next line.
# (Again, the address is an example only.)
#broadcast 192.168.123.255

# If you want to listen to time broadcasts on your local subnet, de-comment the
# next lines.  Please do this only if you trust everybody on the network!
#disable auth
```

#broadcastclient

timedatectl status

```
               Local time: Fri 2022-09-23 17:21:14 MST
           Universal time: Sat 2022-09-24 00:21:14 UTC
                 RTC time: n/a
                Time zone: America/Phoenix (MST, -0700)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

Thanks!

Comment: TLDR; `"I have disabled systemd-timesyncd"`. Why did you do this? `systemd-timesyncd` is (or was when the question last arose) intelligent enough to make adjustments if it detected `ntp` was installed. [REFERENCE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107344/83790). If that doesn't sort it out for you, please let us know & we'll take another look at your details.

Comment: I read on another post it had to be disabled for NTP to work. I guess that isn't right then. I'm just trying to get the system time to update from a local ntp server as it doesn't have access to internet.

Comment: Two things: Thing 1: When you reply to a comment under ***your*** post (Q or A), you need to preface the cmt with the "handle" of the user you want to reach; in my case, that's `@seamus` - the autocomplete will help.  Thing 2: Where did you see that post? AFAIK, the only report of an exception to that is if you build `ntp` from source (I've not confirmed that, but another user reported it).  Anyway - let us know if that works.

Comment: @Seamus, I saw it here: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=266864 (from 2020). I was having this issue before disabling timesyncd, reenabled it, same issue. NTP service: inactive

Comment: I'm confused... are you saying that you've installed NTP while `systemd-timesyncd` was installed & enabled, etc, and that it still doesn't start NTP?

Comment: @Seamus, yes. I just disabled systemd-timesyncd as part of the troubleshooting process. It has never worked right. I can force an update by stopping ntp service and doing sudo ntpdate -s 192.168.2.247, but that is the only way it will update the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These instructions seemed to fix the issue, npt starts with the pi and syncs time now:

```
sudo apt install ntp
sudo systemctl stop systemd-timesyncd
sudo systemctl disable systemd-timesyncd
sudo systemctl enable ntp
sudo systemctl start ntp
```